# Live chart in Pythons matplotlib don't update

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, pyqt5

I'm building a kind of measurement system based on Arduino Nano, because it's cheap and small. It has to measure acceleration, current, torque and voltage, which is not what I'm going to ask about.

Long story short, sensors connected to Arduino are measuring values, which I send through the USB to PC, and then working on it. I've made some application in Python, which is quite complete, but I've got a problem with updating the plots.

I've made my Main.py which is doing things, with GUI made with QT Designer, where I embeded matplotlib. When I'm trying to plot random values, and it's delivered to the mplwidget.py (below), it's working correctly. But when I'm trying to send some data to plotting class from my Main, the whole procedure is working (i've checked it by adding some prints after each step) but visually nothing is happening.

Codes below, as a pastebin links:

- Main.py - https://pastebin.com/R6sHNNRX

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as pq
import PyQt5.QtGui as qg
import threading
import time
import serial
import copy
import csv
import os.path
import types
import datetime
import string
import sys
import random
from gui import Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets, MplWidget

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
w=MplWidget()

#tu pocedury
def start():
    t = threading.Thread(target=readThatSerial, args=(com,runThis), daemon=True)
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()

def potwierdz():
    global com
    com=ui.combo_COM.currentText()
    print(com)
    global pomiar
    pomiar=ui.combo_COM_2.currentText()

ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

#tu zdarzenia
ui.startButton.clicked.connect(start)
ui.PotwierdzButton.clicked.connect(potwierdz)
MainWindow.show()

#tu reszta
def readThatSerial(whichSerial, runRef):
    ser = serial.Serial(whichSerial, 38400, timeout=3)
    whole = ""
    numbers = types.SimpleNamespace()
    numbers.dataNumber = 0
    while(runRef):
        s = ser.read()
        if(len(s) > 0):
            try:
                whole += s.decode("utf-8")
            except Exception as e:
                print("probably decode error: " + str(e))

        lastStart = 0
        for i in range(len(whole)):
            if(whole[i] == "<"):
                data = whole[lastStart:i]
                handleCommand(data, numbers)
                numOfMeas = 0  
                newData = whole[i+1:]
                whole = copy.deepcopy(newData)
                lastStart = i+1

def handleCommand(data, numbers):
    global pomiar
    zm=float(pomiar)*10
    interwal=zm
    parts = data.split("&")
    numbers.dataNumber += 1
    if(numbers.dataNumber % interwal == 0):
        for i in range(len(parts)):    
            if ("=" in parts[i]):                  
                lol = parts[i].split("=")
                print("ai fund da dataaaa: " + parts[i])
                print("name of data " + lol[0])
                print("value of data " + lol[1])
                numbers.dataNumber = 0

        with open('plik.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
            teraz=datetime.datetime.now()
            tim =(teraz.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"))
            czas=list([tim])
            csvwriter.writerow(czas+parts)
            print(czas)
            ui.LCD_ax1.display(parts[0])
            ui.LCD_ay1.display(parts[1])
            ui.LCD_az1.display(parts[2])
            x=[random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(4)]
            w.update_plot(x)

if not os.path.isfile('plik.csv'):
    with open('plik.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csvwriter.writerow(["t", 'a_x', 'a_y', 'a_z', ])
        csvwriter.writerow(["H:m:s:ms",'m/s^2', 'm/s^2', 'm/s^2'])

runThis = True
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

- gui.py - https://pastebin.com/CG6UHvBe

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1373, 760)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.startButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1170, 350, 181, 51))
        self.startButton.setObjectName("startButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 0, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.RichText)
        self.label.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 80, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.LCD_U = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.LCD_U.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 30, 191, 41))
        self.LCD_U.setObjectName("LCD_U")
        self.LCD_I1 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.LCD_I1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 120, 191, 41))
        self.LCD_I1.setObjectName("LCD_I1")
        self.LCD_I2 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.LCD_I2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 210, 191, 41))
        self.LCD_I2.setObjectName("LCD_I2")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 170, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 260, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.LCD_I3 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.LCD_I3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 290, 191, 41))
        self.LCD_I3.setObjectName("LCD_I3")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 260, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.LCD_Moment = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.LCD_Moment.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 290, 191, 41))
        self.LCD_Moment.setObjectName("LCD_Moment")
        self.MplWidget = MplWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.MplWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 731, 701))
        self.MplWidget.setObjectName("MplWidget")
        self.combo_COM = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.combo_COM.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1170, 310, 181, 22))
        self.combo_COM.setObjectName("combo_COM")
        self.combo_COM.addItem("")
        self.combo_COM.addItem("")
        self.combo_COM.addItem("")
        self.combo_COM.addItem("")
        self.combo_COM.addItem("")
        self.combo_COM_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.combo_COM_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 370, 181, 22))
        self.combo_COM_2.setObjectName("combo_COM_2")
        self.combo_COM_2.addItem("")
        self.combo_COM_2.addItem("")
        self.combo_COM_2.addItem("")
        self.combo_COM_2.addItem("")
        self.combo_COM_2.addItem("")
        self.combo_COM_2.addItem("")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1170, 270, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 330, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_13.setFont(font)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1170, 170, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_14.setFont(font)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.LCD_az2 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.LCD_az2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1170, 210, 191, 41))
        self.LCD_az2.setObjectName("LCD_az2")
        self.LCD_ax1 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.LCD_ax1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 30, 191, 41))
        self.LCD_ax1.setObjectName("LCD_ax1")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 0, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.LCD_ay1 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.LCD_ay1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 120, 191, 41))
        self.LCD_ay1.setObjectName("LCD_ay1")
        self.LCD_ay2 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.LCD_ay2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1170, 120, 191, 41))
        self.LCD_ay2.setObjectName("LCD_ay2")
        self.LCD_ax2 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.LCD_ax2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1170, 30, 191, 41))
        self.LCD_ax2.setObjectName("LCD_ax2")
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 90, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_15.setFont(font)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1170, 80, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1170, 0, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.label_6.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.RichText)
        self.label_6.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.LCD_az1 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.LCD_az1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 210, 191, 41))
        self.LCD_az1.setObjectName("LCD_az1")
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 180, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_16.setFont(font)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.PotwierdzButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.PotwierdzButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(964, 350, 201, 51))
        self.PotwierdzButton.setObjectName("PotwierdzButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1373, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.startButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Napięcie"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Prąd 1"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Prąd 2"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Prąd 3"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Moment"))
        self.combo_COM.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "COM1"))
        self.combo_COM.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "COM2"))
        self.combo_COM.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "COM3"))
        self.combo_COM.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "COM4"))
        self.combo_COM.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "COM5"))
        self.combo_COM_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "0.1"))
        self.combo_COM_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "0.2"))
        self.combo_COM_2.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "0.5"))
        self.combo_COM_2.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.combo_COM_2.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.combo_COM_2.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "COM A"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Interwał pomiarowy"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "a_z 2"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "a_x 1"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "a_y 1"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "a_y 2"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "a_x 2"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "a_z 1"))
        self.PotwierdzButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Potwierdź ustawienia"))
from mplwidget import MplWidget


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

- mplwidget.py - https://pastebin.com/eykzUUuu

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import sys
import os
import random
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.compute_initial_figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass

class MplWidget(MyMplCanvas):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MyMplCanvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)        

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        self.axes.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 0, 4], 'r')

    def update_plot(self,x):
        l = x
        print(l)
        print(x)
        self.axes.cla()
        print("a")
        self.axes.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], l, 'r')
        print("b")
        self.draw()
        print("c")
```

Any ideas? Please?